# JIRA - the date/time format of versions on a project

Tags: jira

In a project we can create versions, but the release date format is just d/MMM/yy

Is it possible to have this display the time as well ?

Our datepicker properties are:

```
jira.date.picker.java.format    d/MMM/yy
jira.date.picker.javascript.format  %e/%b/%y
jira.date.time.picker.java.format   dd/MMM/yy h:mm a
jira.date.time.picker.javascript.format %e/%b/%y %I:%M %p
```

we are running JIRA version 6.1.2, build 6157

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[realspirituals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2772061/realspirituals) is right. With standard date field you won't be able to display a time.

Although opposing to the ['Configuring JIRA Options'](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA061/Configuring+JIRA+Options), I found ['Changing the Due Date Input Format'](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA061/Changing+the+Due+Date+Input+Format), which states the possibility of adding a time component to the due date field. But I couldn't find something similar for Release Dates.

A similar [feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-32920) was raisied in May '13 to atlassian.

The only thing I can think of is to add metadata to your version and use a custom field to display it. See here: [new field in version tab panel](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/28303/new-field-in-version-tab-panel). This way you can further handle with it. If you just want to display the time and not "work" with it, just use the description field for that.

Comment: How come in JIRA, nothing is remotely easy. It bugs me that you have to be an Administrator to create Versions. NB: I have not tried your solutio0n but SO required me to choose one & as this is a constructive answer I went with you. Will update it if I have some success.

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+JIRA+Options)

> Date fields, which have no time component, such as due dates, release
>   dates (associated with versions) and custom date fields, solely record
>   date information (and no time zone-related information) so are not
>   affected by time zone settings.

My answer is Not possible and even if you print them, you should get 0's